# About TailwindCSS with Django

Tags: django, tailwind-css

I want to use Tailwind CSS in Django project. When googling, I found following two ways.

1. Use CDN
2. Use Tailwind CLI tool

Using CDN is simpler, so I will use CDN, but [doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/play-cdn) says that CDN is not the best way.

Then I have questions.

1. **Why Using CDN is not the best choice?**
2. **Which is better?**

Answer (score 1):

> Why Using CDN is not the best choice?

Using the CDN might slow down the performance of your page. (Like explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QAIdYGslQGo) [Minute 6:30])

> Which is better?

I would personally choose a local setup, because that's the way thats the way recommended and you should find the most documentation for; and once installed right, it should work smooth and properly.